# Best practice to edit HTML content through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For now let's ignore users without JavaScript and let's ignore accessibility too.
I would like to know what's the best practice to inject a content into a HTML document through JavaScript.

So far, I came up with these solutions:

- create the skeleton of the HTML and fill it through jQuery (using `$(tag).text()`) (though, correct me if I'm wrong, this prevents me from animating the content)
- insert all the content in an HTML format through JS, which allows me to do things like `$("<tag>stuff</p>").fadeIn()` and other things

Note that the fading is used just as an example, I would like to know if there's a best practice in general.

Comment: This looks like an opinion poll rather than a constructive question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm pretty new to web programming in general, I didn't know if this was a "is indenting in C a costraint"-kind of question or a "do you prefer black background or white one?"-kind.

Answer (score 3):

Usually a combination of both I'd say. You may want to create static containers in HTML and dynamic elements that go inside as jQuery elements that you can modify and later append. Ideally you would use some kind of templating solution. The most basic example:

```
function template(data, html) {
  return data.map(function(obj) {
    return html.replace(
      /#\{(\w+)\}/g,
      function(_, match) { return obj[match]; }
    );
  }).join('');
}

var people = [
  { name: 'John', age: 25, status: 'Single' },
  { name: 'Bill', age: 23, status: 'Married' },
  { name: 'Lukas', age: 47, status: 'Married' },
];

var html = template(people,
  '<div>\
    <h1>Name: #{name}</h1>\
    <h2>Age: #{age}, Status: #{status}</h2>\
  </div>'
);

$('#container').append(html);
```

Comment: Ok. I wasn't properly talking about templates, I was referring to dynamically adding single objects to the HTML page.

Say I have a page with a daily quote which is different for every day but it's unique in the page.

Should I fill the **empty** `<blockquote>` tags I placed in the HTML, or should I create the whole HTML (`<blockquote>` + content) from scratch?